Allow <C-Enter> and <S-Enter> to work in bash with apps like nvim
I've notices using showkey -a that +
+ctrl+enter++ and ++shift+enter++ are mapped to code ^M which is ++ctrl+m++ which is a bit weird in case I'm actually using legacy ubuntu 24.04 that enter is tied to a char rather then a cr code and I was wondering whether there is an easy way to fix that manually or have a config that took care of it and made the key combo's ++enter++ and ++ctrl++enter++ distinguishable without interfering with other apps that are built on top of bash (e.g. nvim)
